# How can I set the decimal separator to be a comma?

Tags: c++, formatting, number-formatting, iostream, decimal-point

I would like to read and write *pi* as `3,141592` instead of `3.141592`, as using the comma is common in many European countries. How can I accomplish this with `iostream`s? In other words

```
cout << 3.141592;
```

should print

```
3,141592
```

to standard output.

Comment: You mean, in code? Like `double x = 3,14;`?

Comment: No in standard output, input, reading and writing files at runtime (not at compile time).

Comment: one word: locales.

Comment: I personally do not find this to be an exact duplicate of another question. I found the answers given here much more helpful than the answers to the other question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `basic_ios::imbue` to set the preferred locale.

Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/imbue/

Locales allow you to use the preferred way by the user, so if a computer in Italy uses comma to separate decimal digits, in the US the dot is still used. Using locales is a Good Practice.

But if you want to explicitly force the use of the comma, take a look here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/decimal_point/

Here a small example I just made with g++ which enforces the char ',' (passing the separator as template argument is just for fun, not really necessary)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

template <class charT, charT sep>
class punct_facet: public std::numpunct<charT> {
protected:
    charT do_decimal_point() const { return sep; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new punct_facet<char, ','>));
    std::cout << "My age is " << 3.1415 << " lightyears.\n";
}
```

Note that using `cout.getloc()` I'm overriding just a single facet in the currently set locale, that is, in the current locale settings of cout, I'm changing only how the punctuation is done.

`do_decimal_point` is a virtual function of `std::numpunct` that you can redefine to provide your custom separator. This virtual function will be used by `numpunct::decimal_point` when printing your number.

Answer (score 13):

As @AkiRoss said, you need to use locales.  *In general*, in any
program you write, one of the very first actions in `main`
should be to set the global locale to the users choice, by doing
something like:

```
std::locale::global( std::locale( "" ) );
```

This should be systematic, in *every* program which interacts
with a human user.  All files opened after this will
automatically be imbued with the correct locale.

Alternatively, you can explicitly specify the locale you want to
use:

```
std::locale::global( std::locale( locale_name ) );
```

The problem with this is that there is no standard for locale
names.  Something like `"it_IT.UTF-8"` corresponds to the Posix
standard, and is used on the Internet; Windows has traditionally
used a different format (although recent Windows do seem to
accept this format as well).

Which leaves `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::cerr`.  These are
opened before you enter `main`, and so must be imbued with the
new locale.  (To obtain a copy of the current global locale, use
the default constructor of `std::locale`.)

Finally, if you're opening any binary files, be aware that they
also will be imbued with the global locale.  Which may do code
translation.  In such cases, you should imbue them explicitly
with `std::locale::classic()`, or create a new locale by merging
the `codecvt` facet of `std::locale::classic()` with the other
facets of the global locale.  (`std::locale` has special
functions and constructors for this.)