# Import tab-and-newline-separated CSV data into variables

Tags: c++, csv, import, tabs

Here's a piece of code I use to import my data from a `data.csv` file, into 24 variables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

double xa = 0;
double ya = 0;
double Ta = 0;
double Ca = 0;
double Ma = 0;
double Da = 0;

double xb = 0;
double yb = 0;
double Tb = 0;
double Cb = 0;
double Mb = 0;
double Db = 0;

double xc = 0;
double yc = 0;
double Tc = 0;
double Cc = 0;
double Mc = 0;
double Dc = 0;

double xd = 0;
double yd = 0;
double Td = 0;
double Cd = 0;
double Md = 0;
double Dd = 0;


//__________________________________________________

int trash    = 0;   // ifstream bug (?) stuff

//___________________________________

int main() {


    ifstream ifs ("data.csv"); ///LOADING
if (!ifs)
    // process error
ifs >>  trash;
ifs >>  xa ;
ifs >>  ya ;
ifs >>  Da ;
ifs >>  Ma ;
ifs >>  Ca ;
ifs >>  Ta ;
ifs >>  xb ;
ifs >>  yb ;
ifs >>  Db ;
ifs >>  Mb ;
ifs >>  Cb ;
ifs >>  Tb ;
ifs >>  xc ;
ifs >>  yc ;
ifs >>  Dc ;
ifs >>  Mc ;
ifs >>  Cc ;
ifs >>  Tc ;
ifs >>  xd ;
ifs >>  yd ;
ifs >>  Dd ;
ifs >>  Md ;
ifs >>  Cd ;
ifs >>  Td ;
```

Of course (I guess...,) it works only with this CSV structure (each line contains a new single data:)

```
63.64474122 
5.21472834  
0.40511019  
0.26155648  
0.00000000  
0.00000000
34.45902482 
15.62249852 
0.22086168  
0.00000000  
0.44580498  
0.00000000
82.11020306 
14.02709406 
0.50748794  
0.00000000  
0.00000000  
0.15917872
0.00000000  
0.00000000  
0.00000000  
0.00000000  
0.00000000  
0.00000000
```

For obvious practical reasons, I'd like to use this file structure for the CSV (tab-and-newlines-separated):

```
63,64474122 5,21472834  0,40511019  0,26155648  0,00000000  0,00000000
34,45902482 15,62249852 0,22086168  0,00000000  0,44580498  0,00000000
82,11020306 14,02709406 0,50748794  0,00000000  0,00000000  0,15917872
0,00000000  0,00000000  0,00000000  0,00000000  0,00000000  0,00000000
```

Could somebody help me there?

Comment: sorry for the commas in the example, I meant floating points!

Answer (score 1):

Your code (as abysmal as it is) is supposed to work fine with both files. `iostream` input operators treat input as a *stream*, which means that for types like `int` or `double` they don't care how the values are separated (by newlines or by blanks).

Now, taking a closer look, I see that the second file uses commas instead of decimal points. There are 3 ways you can handle this:

- You can force the locale to be one that treats comma as a decimal point (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/how-can-i-set-the-comma-to-be-a-decimal-point))
- You can preprocess file using a script before reading it by your program.
- Finally, you can read each number into an `std::string` variable first and then using  `std::istringstream` convert it to `double`.

In any case, you should seriously consider reading up on `iostream` usage. At the very least you should check for input errors. And no, there is no such thing as *"ifstream bug"*.

Comment: Well yes, I'm the bug, I know... However, with the second file structure (tabulations,) this code doesn't works. You mention "newlines" and "blanks" as separators, it doesn't make it with blanks as well... Sorry for being such a wild cryptic C++ user, that's really not my profession...

Comment: Please see the clarification above.

Comment: thank you, it's my mistake... the file I tested used decimal points (not commas) and didn't load properly... but it's good to know I can use commas...