# Currency format using double values

Tags: c++, format, currency

How can get currency format from double values? The following snippet works fine with integers while it doesn't with doubles?!

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ostringstream stream;
    stream.imbue(std::locale(""));
    stream << setprecision(3) <<194663.33;
    string stringValue = stream.str();
    cout << stringValue;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using M$ Visual Studio 2012 while I didn't face this issue using gcc under Linux (I used `sprintf(buffer, WString("%'.3f")` )

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work with `double`? Can you show us the output using both `int` and `double` and what you expected please?

Comment: You should not express currency values in binary floating points

Comment: for:194663.33  I got `1.95e+005` for:194663 I got `194,663`

Comment: @DieterLücking unfortunately I've to use doubles

Comment: I expect to get: `194,663.33`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class punct_facet: public std::numpunct<char>
{
    char do_decimal_point() const { return '.'; }
    char do_thousands_sep() const { return ','; }
    std::string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};
void main()
{
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new punct_facet));
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << "Formatted number: " << 194663.33 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Formatted number: 194,663.33
```

You can find more information here:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/numpunct/
- [How can I set the comma to be a decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/how-can-i-set-the-comma-to-be-a-decimal-point)
- http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/formatting.pdf