# Can I read double values from istream that have different digit separator?

Tags: c++, double, istream

I want in my program read double values from different text files. Some files contain doubles in format 'xx.yyy' (dot is a separator), but some other - 'xx,yyy' (comma is a separator). I use c++ streams for reading.

Comment: What is the format of the text files? Are values stored every line? Add file content to your question.

Comment: For example one file is:  <br/>

12.33 12.55  <br/>

-9.09 1000.01  <br/>


And other file:  

100,09 12,4  

99,99 2,00  
 
-1,002 1,09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format of each file ahead of time, you can [`imbue()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) a [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) with a custom [`std::locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) whose [`std::numpunct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct) facet specifies the desired `thousands_sep` and `decimal_point` characters. Then [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) will be able to parse the `double` values as expected.

See [How can I set the decimal separator to be a comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/) for how to specify a custom `decimal_point`. The same approach applies to `thousands_sep` as well.

If you don't know the format ahead of time, you will have to read the `double`s as strings first, then manually parse them to determine which format they are using, and then you can `imbue()` a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) as needed to then convert the strings to `double`.  If all of the `double`s in a given file use the same format, then you could do this for the 1st `double` and then `imbue()` the `std::ifstream` as needed for subsequent `double`s.