# When people input floating numbers with comma my c++ program collapses

Tags: c++, input, console, numbers, floating

So I am at the start of my programming career and I wrote a code for a simple vending machine on C++.

The problem is, when people pay, they need to input their change into the console like: " 0.50€" for 50 cents. The problem is I live in Europe, and most of the people put in commas as floating numbers like "0,50€". The program collapses when this happens. How do I solve this elegantly? With either the program discovering it and mentions their failure so they can type it in correctly or, better, accepts it as a normal floating-point number.

Comment: It would help if you post the relevant code fragment and explain what exactly goes wrong, for example, does your program crash or do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of locale settings.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/how-can-i-set-the-decimal-separator-to-be-a-comma) may help you in setting the locale you need in your program.

Comment: it is inside a while loop infinitively saying I need to pay the rest amount

Comment: Don't describe it, put the code in the question