# Why debugging and running outputs are different in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to read ".text" file and convert string as double. In debug mode i can read text as 99,03 but in running mode i can read only 99. I can't understand how it would be? My converting code is below

```
   double a = std::stod(text)
```

Comment: You might have a different locale setting between debug and release.

Comment: Perhaps "running mode" is using a different locale to "debug mode".  In US numeric locales, `99,03` are two integers separated by a comma.  In some European locales, `99,03` is a decimal value 99.03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stod` is affected by locale.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>

int main(void){
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");

    std::string s{"99.03"}; 
    double d = std::stod( s );
    std::cout<< d << "\n";
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8"); // A locale installed on your machine.
    std::string s2{"99,03"};
    double d2 = std::stod( s2 );
    std::cout<< d2 << "\n";
}
```

You may get the result as following: ( tested on msvc and gcc 9.3.0 )

```
99.03
99.03
```

If you want `std::cout` also print comma as decimal separator, `imbue` is required. You may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220861/how-can-i-set-the-decimal-separator-to-be-a-comma).